# Append data in pandas

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I can't figure out how to add data to a column in a panda data frame.

I have four sensors that are sampling in four threads. I would like each sensor to append the current value to a specific column in a panda data frame.

For example:

I have a .csv file with only the header:

```
p1,p2,p3,c
```

I want the threads to add a value to the column. So after the first sample on the first sensor the data frame would have.

```
p1 p2  p3  c
3  NaN NaN NaN
```

The next sensor should then add a value like this

```
p1 p2  p3  c
3  5   NaN NaN
```

I have search for appending, but I can't figure out how the code should be.

Comment: do you have something you can index on? You either need to be sure that everything is sorted exactly the same way or have a column that is unique to each observation.

Comment: I am passing the column name p1/p2/p3 or c to the thread..

Comment: I was thinking you were trying to merge 4 columns into one. I'm not sure you really need to use pandas to merge between threads, why not use something like SQLite or just use a simple numpy array? You could chunk your calls (i.e., generate 5+ values at a time), keep track of where you are in terms of observations, and then send update/insert commands on the fly to fill the columns. Seems like that would be much more efficient. For the numpy array, you could pass the column index instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some column that is unique to each observation (let's call it "ObservationID"), then it's really simple to do this.  You can use either `pandas.concat` or `pandas.merge`. I'll go with `concat` because I find it slightly simpler.

```
import pandas as pd

sensor1 = pd.DataFrame({"p1":[5,2,3], "ObservationID":[22, 31, 14]})
sensor2 = pd.DataFrame({"p2":[1,1,0], "ObservationID":[22, 31, 14]})

# first, set index column to be unique
sensor1_indexed = sensor1.set_index(["ObservationID"])
sensor2_indexed = sensor2.set_index(["ObservationID"])

sensors = pd.concat([sensor1_indexed, sensor2_indexed], axis=1)
```

If you can order them the same way, you can add `ignore_index=True` to do the concatenation:

```
sensors = pd.concat([sensor1, sensor2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Finally, you could also do this with `pd.merge`, but I don't really see why you would need to (unless you had columns with the same name on both parts, then you either need to use merge or pick one of the sensors to win).  To do that, you need a join condition (so that's why we're using the unindexed sensors for this):

```
sensors = pd.merge(sensor1, sensor2, how="inner", on=["ObservationID"])
```

Note that `pd.concat` takes a list of objects and can concatenate as many elements as you want in one call, which could be more convenient if you have multiple sensors.